# How to have a node server compress IMGs coming from a certain path before sending the reply

Tags: node.js, express, web, http-compression

I have a node.js with express running on Heroku linked to a github repository, it is serving a website which also contains a "gallery" section.
The pictures in the gallery are loaded in very high res by other non tech-savvy admins, to prevent huge data usage from mobile users.

I would like the express.js server to downscale and compress the images coming from a certain path when requested by a normal get request before sending them as reply.
Could you help me understand how can i "intercept" those requests ? or at least route me in a certain direction ?

Sorry to ask it here and like this, but i tryed looking many wikis and some questions here on stackoverflow but none seems to talk about what i'm searching
(at least from my understanding).

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why you are serving High-res images? Convert images at once and serve compressed images always.

Comment: unfortunately i cannot, else i'd have done it, my server is running on free heroku, so no storage, it's linked to a github repo that is deployed to it on commit

Comment: Okay, can you not push compressed images on GitHub?. One question, you want to serve lo-res images to all users or some/specific users?

Comment: I want to serve them to any user, unfortunately as i said above, imgs are pushed by non tecchy admins and i would like this to be handled by the server (If i can i prefer being able to avoid going compress an image everytime they upload a new one (speaking of > 1k images here))
Thank you for you patience and understanding